# expression tree evaluation

Tags: scheme, expression-trees

I'm trying to evaluate an expression tree. Here is my code:

```
(define (eval-tree expr-tree)
  (eval-treeaux eval-tree expr-tree))

(define (eval-treeaux f expr-tree)
  (if (null? expr-tree)
      0
      (cond ((equal? '+ (operator expr-tree)) (+ (left-op expr-tree) (right-op expr-tree)))
            ((equal? '- (operator expr-tree)) (- (left-op expr-tree) (right-op expr-tree)))
            ((equal? '* (operator expr-tree)) (* (left-op expr-tree) (right-op expr-tree)))
            ((equal? '/ (operator expr-tree)) (/ (left-op expr-tree) (right-op expr-tree)))
            (else (f eval-treeaux expr-tree)))))
```

When I run this `(eval-tree '((6 * 3) + (4 - 2)))`, it gives me this error:

```
+: expects type <number> as 1st argument, given: (6 * 3); other arguments 
   were: (4 - 2)
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem is and how I can fix it?

---

Here is my new code:

```
(define (eval-tree expr-tree)
  (if (null? expr-tree)
      0
      ((eval-treeaux eval-tree (car expr-tree)) (eval-tree (cdr expr-tree)))))

(define (eval-treeaux f expr-tree)
  (cond ((null? expr-tree) '())
        ((not (isExpression expr-tree)) (list expr-tree))
        (else (cond ((equal? '+ (operator expr-tree)) (+ (left-op expr-tree) (right-op expr-tree)))
                    ((equal? '- (operator expr-tree)) (- (left-op expr-tree) (right-op expr-tree)))
                    ((equal? '* (operator expr-tree)) (* (left-op expr-tree) (right-op expr-tree)))
                    ((equal? '/ (operator expr-tree)) (/ (left-op expr-tree) (right-op expr-tree)))
                    (else (f eval-treeaux expr-tree))))))
```

But, when I run this `(eval-tree '((6 * 3) + (4 - 2)))`, I get this error:

```
procedure application: expected procedure, given: 2; arguments were: 0
```

I'm really confused. Can anyone help me please?
Thanks

Comment: I concur with the answer below.  A separate issue: why are you returning zero on empty lists? Also, why have you separated this function into eval-tree and eval-treeaux? Also, why are you passing eval-tree to eval-treeaux? This code needs a lot of cleanup!

Answer (score 1):

The expression `((6 * 3) + (4 - 2))` appears to be composed 2 subexpressions:

```
 (6 * 3)  ; e_1
 (4 - 2)  ; e_2
```

You need to recursively evaluate the subexpressions before you can evaluate the parent expression.

Comment: This is what I thought I was doing in my else statement in the aux function. Do I need another recursive function? I'm not sure what the recursive expression would be though.

Comment: @prgrammer: It's not enough to do it in the `else`; you must also do it for the operands of the `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, though that approach gets ugly. You will want to recurse into each sub-branch, but refactor do it cleanly.